# Как сделать сортировку названий как в проводнике Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Есть список файлов и если на Python сделать `sort()`, то список получаеться не такой же как в проводнике Windows (сортировка по имени).

Как сделать сортировку по имени такой же как и в Windows Проводнике?

Comment: Стоило бы конкретные примеры добавить.

Comment: Так  как там сортируется лексикографически, то получается 100.png < 12.png и подобное, а в проводнике 12.png , 100.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

воспользуйтесь модулем [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
In [45]: from natsort import natsorted   #  pip install natsort

In [46]: files = ["7.png", "10.png", "5.png"]

In [47]: sorted(files)                 # Vanilla Python sorting
Out[47]: ['10.png', '5.png', '7.png']

In [48]: natsorted(files)              # natsort sorting
Out[48]: ['5.png', '7.png', '10.png']
```